# Multivariable calc "second course" that does differential forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation, differential-forms

I've worked through a computation-heavy, "standard" but **quite nonrigorous** treatment of multivariable calculus in the past. What book would do well as a rigorous (but not overly) "second course"? In particular, I'm looking for a book that

- treats differential forms
- treats the inverse and implicit function theorems

and leads well into an intro manifolds book like Tu's one. (Bonus points if it actually talks a bit about manifolds itself or works with differential forms defined on manifolds instead of only $\Bbb R^n$!)

Comment: Zorich's *Mathematical Analys* (vol. I & II) perhaps?

Comment: I do not think I want an analysis book. I'd like something with plenty of pictures and one that does not spend a lot of time with epsilon-delta arguments. (My idea of analysis books is that they don't do that kind of thing; I may be wrong.)

Comment: Fine, it was just a suggestion. But what do you mean by "treating" the inverse and implicit function theorems then? I got the impression that you already know how to use them, and were looking for a more advanced book where you could see how they actually are proved.

Comment: No, I do not know those two theorems. I only know that they are something that I should know before studying manifolds.

Comment: I see. Yes, in that case, some other book is probably more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible recommendations - I'm not 100% sure if what you are looking for exists but these are all well-written and worth investigating.

- [Edwards](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817637079), Advanced calculus: a differential forms approach
- [Bloch](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817681227), A First Course in Geometric Topology and Differential Geometry
- [Bachmann](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817683030), A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms

The last one is particularly nice, in my opinion.

Comment: Bachmann doesn't do the implicit function theorem, I suppose. :(

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure - it might be in the "Prerequisites" section.