# Why is it legitimate to perform multiplication with differentials dx?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

Why is it legitimate to perform multiplication with differentials $dx$?

For instance, from the statement $dy = 5dx$ one derives $\frac{dy}{dx} = 5$.

I learned $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a notation to mean the limit of the rate of change.

In this [MIT OpenCourseWare video](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/video-lectures/lecture-11-chain-rule/), the professor states that $dx$ is not a number but doesn't define what it is precisely.

Is there a book/online doc that talks about why it is legitimate to manuplate $dx$ as if it were a value?

Comment: $df(x)$ is defined as $df(x) := f'(x)dx$.  So it's not that you're dividing by $dx$ on both sides, it's just that you're recognizing $5$ as the derivative of $y$ from your equation.  As for a book on differential forms, how good is your multivariable calculus?  If you're pretty confident on it, check out [the answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525309/multivariable-calc-second-course-that-does-differential-forms).  If not, you're just going to have to wait for now.

Comment: I didn't know there is a definition for df(x) .. Where can I learn that?

Comment: Any book on differential forms.  For a really brief introduction you could take a look at [this pdf](http://math.umn.edu/~bpawlows/teaching/324sp12/ec3.pdf).  It defines $df$ on page $3$ with partial derivatives, but of course if $f$ is a function of only $1$ variable, then you'd just use the regular derivative.

Comment: The direction you're questioning makes me curious. $\;\;\;$ How did you get $\: dy = 5dx \:$ in the first place? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I just gave a simple example I could make up, it's presented in the class (online lecture)

Comment: I asked the related question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534494/learning-mathematics-and-you-feel-cheated , please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the manipulations people do with differentials can be understood by thinking of $dx$ as a *differential form*. Unfortunately, it's hard to find a good introduction to differential forms that doesn't assume the reader is already very comfortable with calculus. You might try David Bachman's [*A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=l6ERn6lWgL8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).